Questionable Threads - Are these on-or off topic?
Post questionable threads here, using one reply per thread. No need to vote on each one (as then the people that reported the thread get down voted), but please add comments to each thread reasoning why on or off topic.

Voting on meta doesn't affect reputation, so we could vote on them.

fair enough - though I suppose people ould vote by just going and voting to close them ;) as long as there is some discussion around some of this "grey-area" questions to figure out where we are headed...

Effect on World Economy if Bitcoin Was Adopted
What would the effects be on the world economy if several million people around the world would utilize the Bitcoin currency for their daily transactions? Would you expect the GDP to grow faster or slower and why?

my vote: off-topic, way too speculative and subject to debate. I have no idea how a case could be made that this is a good SE-type question with a verifiable expert answer.

Is Performance Really Important When Choosing a Language for a Trading Bot
The C programming language outperforms interpreted languages such as Python or Ruby, but when it comes down to programming productivity, it is much easier/faster to write a Python program than a C program.
Considering that I want to write a trading bot, what would be the most appropriate language? If I use C, will I see a noticeable performance difference, or would the latency from HTTP calls make my decision time irrelevant?

my vote: off-topic. not specific enough to bitcoin as a technology, could be answered in a general programming question.

The thing is, the reason it's off-topic is that there's nothing special about Bitcoin trading that impacts the question. But the fact that there's nothing special itself is on topic.

Writing a trading bot for a high-paced market is very different from trading at MtGox. A 100ms difference between decision times is important there (not to mention the fact that their APIs are much more solid - MtGox's API is awful to deal with...). So if I asked this question anywhere else, I would have to refer Bitcoin specifically. That is why I thought it was appropriate to ask here.

maybe those assumptions could be spelled out better in the question? Something like "What are the issues (performance and otherwise) I need to be aware of when writing a trading bot for the MtGox API?"

Yes, I agree that I should have spelled the question better. It was late and I wrote it in a hurry. Anyway, I got the answers I wanted.

Costing arbitrage between exchanges
I'm currently writing something to script arbitrage between two exchanges to test the concept.
I know I can determine the difference in prices by using
(ExhangeA_sell - ExchangeB_buy) <- this will give me the price difference. i.e. gross profit (before fee's)
My question, how do I take the fee's into account when calculating net profit?

[this seems like a basic math question, not a bitcoin question]

Why Did Paypal Ban bitcoins when Google Checkout did not yet?
Beyond conspiracy theories (that my or may not be true), Paypal claimed they were not allowed to sell Bitcoins, while currently it seems Google Checkout is a viable option (at least two sites I know that use GC and a Google employee explicitly allowed virtual currencies in a reply to a Bitcoin question.).

not sure. my thoughts I guess so as far as topicality, but this seems like if there is an answer, it is easily researched (looking for an official statement by the companies in question) and if there isn't an answer, it is just going to speculation on the part of whomever is answering.

I think the only problem with this question is that, as phrased, it invites bad answers. It is trying to ask a fairly simple factual question that is Bitcoin related.

I tried to rephrase it and make it more appropriate.
